Cartoon where the main character has a bag of jewels that make his friend stronger
The main character was male. I don't know which country the cartoon is from and I don't remember the main character's appearance. He had a bag of, I think, red jewels and a red/yellow animal friend. The gems made his friend stronger?
It's not Huntik or Magi-Nation. I watched this on either Cartoon Network, Nickelodeon or Chutti TV, in India, between 2008 and 2010 or so.

Is this Zinba (2013)...?
From MyAnimeList:

The juvenile Kan from the earth is summoned to the Kingdom of Toria , where he encounters attack from the giant creature Zinba, and he's rescued by the linker Shibuki and Uranus. Later, he accidentally gets on the linker squad DUX truck to the maze valley, finding in a cave a golden Zinba.

A teenage boy from Earth, Kan, is transported to another world where various types of monsters exist. At one point in the first episode, he hears people coming his way and hides in some bushes. He then sees a group of uniformed men run past, carrying backpacks full of multi-coloured gems. A red gem falls out of one of the backpacks and lands on the ground, then, after the men have gone, Kan comes out of the bushes and picks it up. He subsequently encounters and forms an alliance with Zinba, a small yellow and red creature resembling a lion cub, which grows into a gigantic lion monster when the red gem is placed in an indentation on its forehead.



